# When creating a UserControl that uses a grid, is there any reason not to just change the base class type to Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, subclass

Simple question.  Most UserControls inherit from UserControl, then have as their child, a grid.  I've never really understood why.  I mostly just go change the base type to Grid in both the XAML and the code-behind and it seems to work exactly the same, albeit with a now-simpler visual tree.  And if it's a different control than grid, we do the same thing.  For instance, Border is a frequent base-class choice for us.

However, when digging around in the internals of UserControl (which has the exact same interface as its base class ContentControl. Everything is inherited, the internal implementation of some of the properties are overridden for a UserControl. You can see this using Reflector or any other tool to dig into the code.  However, I'm not sure any of that matters, and to date, we haven't noticed any ill side-effects of changing the base class.

So does anyone have any information that we aren't privy to about this?

Comment: No, a custom control is also known as a Lookless control where the UI is defined via a style with a key set to the type of the class and which specifies the control template.  I am talking about a UserControl which uses an associated XAML file and relies on InitializeComponent() to initialize it.  I am simply changing the base class from UserControl to Grid.  Try it yourself.  Create a UserControl.  Then in the code-behind, change UserControl to Grid, then go back and update the Class attribute of the xaml file.  That is what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry to post an answer, my text is too long for a comment) Your statement about the interface of the control differs depending on your base class. Lets say you have a class `Car` and `Car` has a `Steering Wheel` because most likely every car in the world has a steering wheel. You implement a `Porsche` by deriving `Porsche` from `Car`. You add some special Porsche properties to `Porsche`, thats it. Of course `Porsche` also has a `Steering Wheel` -> thats what you really want.

Now you need a `Garage` class. You also can inherit `Car` to get the `Garage`. That does work! But makes little sense (your garage now has a steering wheel).

The same applies when you inherit your user control from `Grid`. The Interface of your control exposes all properties and methods of `Grid` (defining columns and rows, ...)! Is that what you want? Most likely not.

From a documentation and maintainability perspective it is a good idea to use a clean light weight base class for a user control and expose only those properties (and methods) that make up the Interface of your control. The first choice is still `UserControl`.

In other words your `Grid` is an implementation detail of your user control. But it is (most likely) not the Interface of the user control.

Small sidenote. Even 5 years old PCs are powerful enough so that an additional layer in the visual tree doesn't hurt.

Comment: Very good points about exposing the properties of Grid. However, by that logic, why would I want UserControl exposing its content property?  And sometimes you *do* want to expose the base-class properties, such as subclassing from Border instead of UserControl, which is something else we do a lot.  But design aside, I'm trying to figure out the *technical* need for the *concrete* UserControl class instead of just using a ContentControl as the base class for a UserControl code template.  It's all in the properties that are overridden but I can't seem to find any explanation of their intent.